# How do I use the python turtle on click function to clear the canvas?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is for a school project - I am still a beginner and have lots of trouble with functions. How would I clear the canvas with a click?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how severe a clearing you want to do.  If you simply want to remove the drawing done by an individual turtle, but leave drawings by other turtles (background) in tact, as well as preserve aspects of the screen like its background color, you can use the screen's `onclick()` event to invoke *an individual turtle's* `clear()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def clear_turtle(x, y):
    turtle.clear()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('lavender')
screen.onclick(clear_turtle)

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.hideturtle()
yertle.dot(100)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.dot(50, 'yellow')

screen.mainloop()
```

If, on the other hand, you want a more scorched earth result, you can use the screen's `onclick()` event to invoke *the screen's* `clear()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def clear_screen(x, y):
    screen.clear()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('lavender')
screen.onclick(clear_screen)

yertle = Turtle()
yertle.hideturtle()
yertle.dot(100)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.dot(50, 'yellow')

screen.mainloop()
```

This will return the screen to it's initial blank (white) state and destroy all your turtle drawings as well as your turtles all the way down.